# MediaWiki API Extension JSON

Tags: json, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

I have developed a MediaWiki extension that gets a (JSON) string from an external service using cURL.

Now I'm looking for a way to retrieve just that string from the MediaWiki system. (This URL will be used for AJAX calls.)

First, I thought that MediaWiki API was the way to do that. However, I can't seem to be able to output just that string.

What would be the right way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

Thank you, that did the trick. For your information, here's how far I got:

```
$this->getResult()->addValue(null, null, array( 'autocomplete' => array( 'server', 'servers' ) ) );
```

returns `[{"autocomplete":["server","servers"]}]` when appending `format=json` to the API URL. Instead of the above JSON string, the JavaScript client I'm working with needs `{"autocomplete":["server","servers"]}` in order to work correctly. In other words, I needed to get rid of `[` and `]`.

Just out of curiosity, is a custom printer still the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your API module, override `getCustomPrinter()`:

```
public function getCustomPrinter() {
    return new ApiFormatRaw(
        $this->getMain(),
        $this->getMain()->createPrinterByName( 'json' )
    );
}
```

(the nested `createPrinterByName()` call is for fallback format in case of errors, you can change it to some other format)

Then, in your `execute()` method or wherever you need to return the value:

```
$this->getResult()->addValue( null, 'text', $data_you_want_to_return );
$this->getResult()->addValue( null, 'mime', 'application/json' );
```